# How to change color of a set of nodes in kinetic js?

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

SO I have a lot of Kinetic polygons, and I collect them and store in a variable like this:

```
var midr = layer.find('.midr');
```

I want to change their colors, so I want to delete them and draw them with different colour:

```
          midr.on('mouseover',function(){
                midr.destroy();
                Boxes.MidR(color.R,color.G,color.B,1,'midr');
                midr = layer.find('.midr');
          });
          midr.on('mouseout',function(){
                midr.destroy();
                Boxes.MidR(color.R,color.G,color.B,0,'midr');
                midr = layer.find('.midr');
          });
```

where:

```
    var Boxes={
                  .....
            MidR:function(R,G,B,A,group){
            var C = shade(R,G,B,25,"+");
            Mid_right.left(C.r,C.g,C.b,A,group);
            var C = shade(R,G,B,20,"-");
            Mid_right.back(C.r,C.g,C.b,A,group);            
            Mid_right.right(R,G,B,A,group);
            Mid_right.bottom(R,G,B,A,group);
            Mid_right.shelf(R,G,B,A,group);
        },           ....
    }
```

and

```
var Mid_right={
        left:function(R,G,B,A,group){
            frame([89,192,120,192,120,309,89,315],150,150,150,A,group);
            frame([75,311,89,315,89,192,75,192],R,G,B,A,group)
        },
        right:function(R,G,B,A,group){
            frame([99,193.5,99,306,118.5,309,118.5,193.5],R,G,B,A,group)
        },
        back:function(R,G,B,A,group){
            frame([90.5,308,99,306,99,193.5,90.5,193.5],R,G,B,A,group);
        },
        shelf:function(R,G,B,A,group){
            frame([90.5,270,118.5,266,99,264,90.5,265],R,G,B,A,group)
        },
        bottom:function(R,G,B,A,group){
            frame([120,309,99,306,90.5,308,90.5,315],R,G,B,A,group)
        }
    };
```

and

```
function frame(array,R,G,B,A,group){
    poly = new Kinetic.Polygon({
        points: array,
        stroke: 'white',
        strokeWidth: 1,
        name: group
    });
    if(R!=null||G!=null||B!=null){
        poly.setFill('rgba('+R+','+G+','+B+','+A+')');
    } else {
        poly.setFill('rgba(0,0,0,0)');
    };
    layer.add(poly);
};
```

maybe it is kind of stupid and I could do it much easier, but there are other things I have to think about, which are not included here and I thought this should be a good way.

so what I want is to delete a set of polygons then redraw them with different colour, when the mouse hovers them and when it leaves, it should change back to original. but using destroy, redraw, and then collecting them again does not seem to work, dont know why. any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of removing/recreating the poly, just use myPoly.setFill inside the mouseover and mouseleave events:

- Add 2 additional properties to your poly: hoverColor and blurColor,
- On mouseover:  this.setFill(this.hoverColor);
- On mouseleave: this.setFill(this.blurColor);

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/GTe9j/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.7.2.min.js"></script>

<style>
body{padding:20px;}
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 350,
        height: 350
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    newPoly("red","green",[50,50, 100,50, 50,100]);
    newPoly("blue","green",[100,50, 150,50, 150,100]);
    newPoly("orange","green",[150,100, 150,150, 100,150]);
    newPoly("purple","green",[100,150, 50,150, 50,100]);


    function newPoly(hovercolor,blurcolor,array){

        var poly = new Kinetic.Polygon({
            points: array,
            stroke: 'gray',
            strokeWidth: 1,
            fill:blurcolor
        });
        poly.hoverColor=hovercolor;
        poly.blurColor=blurcolor;
        poly.on("mouseover",function(){
            this.setFill(this.hoverColor);
            this.draw();
        });
        poly.on("mouseleave",function(){
            this.setFill(this.blurColor);
            this.draw();
        });
        layer.add(poly);
        layer.draw();

    }


}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <h4>Hover over a triangle to change its hover-color</h4>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thats great, but I have to change the color of more polygons when one is entered, I have to change all the polys with different shades of colours, which are hard coded in objects. and when i delete and redraw the polygons, i can set their color with the right shades.

Comment: So hovering on the poly's group changes all polys to their hover-fill?  Try this variation: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/HpWTL/  Anyway, the ideas is to use setFill instead of remove/recreate.